# Add date picker as a subview

Tags: ios, datepicker, subview

I am trying to add a date picker to my iPad application.  How do I add this as a sub view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what I use

```
UIDatePicker *datePicker = [[UIDatePicker alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 40, 0, 0)];
// ... populate your date picker and format it as you see fit.
[self.view addSubview:datePicker];
```

Comment: How to remove this datePicker from that particular view?

Comment: @rasi `[datePicker removeFromSuperview];`